# Jackson - POJO to JSON include both @JSONProperty as well as fieldName in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

Currently using jackson version 2.5.0. Below is POJO:

```
class Employee {
  
  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  public String emp_fname;

  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  public String emp_lname;
  
  public Integer emp_age;
 
  // Getter and Setters for same
}
```

I need JSON as below:

```
{
  "firstName": "XXX",
  "emp_fname": "XXX",
  "lastName": "YYY",
  "emp_lname": "YYY",
  "emp_age": 29
}
```

How to instruct Jackson 2.5.0 to include both property as well as fieldname in JSON structure.

*@JsonAlias annotation is introduced in 2.9.0 so other than any solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonProperty`, can only be used to specify one property. However, you can write two getter methods that return the same variable:

```
@JsonProperty("emp_lname")
public String getEmp_lname() { return emp_lname } ;

@JsonProperty("lastName")
public String getLastName() { return emp_lname } ;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply... Is there any application level config for same so that it gets applicable to all pojo...

Comment: @JsonAlias is only used during deserializarion. there is no annotation or configuration that causes Jackson to serialize a proerpty multiple times